# Length of lists in array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using [scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point.html) to get the number of data points within a specific radius from each point in a grid layout.

It works but returns me an array of lists, and I only need the length of each list. Of course I can iterate through the array, but there must be a smart way to get the length of each list in an array of lists, or maybe another way to find the number of data points that are within a specific radius from each grid point.

Any ideas of how to do this the most efficient?

Comment: Be more specific about what you get.  The answers so far treat this as a list of lists and iterate.

Comment: From the docs: `If x is an array of points, returns an object array of shape tuple containing lists of neighbors`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the array of neighbour counts? If you just wanted the sum over all points then you could use the [`.count_neighbours()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.count_neighbors.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.count_neighbors) method.

Answer (score 2):

Call len() on each element in the array

ie

```
lengths=[len(x) for x in myarray]
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs for this function say it returns a

> If x is an array of points, returns an object array of `shape tuple` containing lists of neighbors

where

> x : array_like, `shape tuple` + (self.m,)

The talk of `shape tuple` is a little unclear, but I think it refers `x.shape[:-1]`, all but the last dimension of the input array.  So for `n` points in a 2d space, `x` will be `(n,2)`, and the result will be shape (n,).

For a simple 1d array of lists, just plain list comprehension is the best way:

```
In [36]: x=np.array([[1,2,3],[],[3,4]])

In [37]: x
Out[37]: array([[1, 2, 3], [], [3, 4]], dtype=object)

In [39]: [len(i) for i in x]
Out[39]: [3, 0, 2]
```

`len(x)` and `x.shape` apply to the array itself, not any elements.

`x` contains pointers to the lists; so any operation on those lists requires a Python access to those lists.  There aren't many vectorized array operations that propagate down to the elements of an object array.  After all the elements of such an array may be anything, including `None`.

If you input array is higher dimensional, e.g. `(10,20,2)`, a 10x20 grid of points, it's probably easiest to flatten this first.

```
In [50]: X
Out[50]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3], [1]],
       [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]]], dtype=object)

In [51]: np.array([len(i) for i in X.flat]).reshape(2,2)
Out[51]: 
array([[3, 1],
       [3, 2]])
```

In sum - list comprehension is the way to go, even though it is an array.

===============

There is another way of iterating over an array that handles multidimensions well.  In some tests it may save 20% over list iterations, the use of `np.frompyfunc`.

```
np.frompyfunc(len,1,1)(x).astype(int)
```

It returns an array of the right shape, though it too is dtype object, hence the `astype` tag.  `np.vectorize` uses this, but makes no claim to improving speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a more ''mathematical'' way:

```
lengths = map(len, myarray)
```

It will return a `map` object you can iterate.

Comment: "mathematical" is also called *functional programming*. In python list comprehension is faster than functional programming usually though. But +1 for having another option.

Comment: Not all the time. With a list comprehension, you have a list with all the data but with a map, you have a lazy generator that will gives you the data when you need them. If you have a really big set of data, being lazy is great!

Comment: Depends which version of python are you using. In python 2.7 map gives you a list, just as list comprehension. You have to use [imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) if you want a *generator*. But the same list comprehension expresion can be written (in both python 2.7 and 3.x) to give a generator `(len(x) for x in myarray)` that will calculate the values *lazily*, just like *imap* (or *map* in python 3.x)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for this: scipy.spatial.cKDTree.count_neighbors